# Roy Language for Meteor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, meteorite

Can anyone guide me in using the [Roy JavaScript Language](http://roy.brianmckenna.org/) with [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/)? There are already options for using vanilla JavaScript and CoffeeScript with Meteor, but I like Roy more and I'm not sure how to use another language like Roy. Is there a Meteorite package for it?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is a reasonable question.

Comment: :) thanks @BenjaminRH - I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Im wondering too! This is a good question there's nothing wrong about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/) currently doesn't show any packages for Roy.

You could write the roy compiler smart package yourself. It's fairly easy - see the sources of  [CoffeeScript plugin](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/coffeescript). Another example is the [TypeScript compiler plugin](https://github.com/orefalo/meteor-typescript-compiler).

Alternatively you could compile `.roy` files outside `meteor` using a bash script. Here's one that recursively monitors the current directory and executes `roy file.roy` whenever a `.roy` file is written.

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -mr -e CLOSE_WRITE . |  while read dir evt file; do 
    in=$dir$file;
    [[ $in =~ ([.]roy$) ]] && roy $in
done
```

Note that this script does not remove result `.js` file when the corresponding `.roy` file is deleted or renamed.